# mousemove - if Y is increasing faster than X is increasing/decreasing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a "mega menu" where hovering over the top level navigation reveals 100% width panels below the nav and slides them in and out depending on which direction you move your mouse over the top level navigation. Currently this is working pretty well, but I'm having an issue where if you move your mouse towards a link in the panel, you might accidentally hover the next `li` over while you're moving your mouse into the panel. I think I have a solution for this based on calculating the X and Y position of the mouse and then determining if the Y position is increasing more rapidly than the X position is increasing/decreasing.

How can I calculate this?

So far I have the following:

```js
$('body').mousemove(function(e) {
    console.log('X ' + e.pageX);
    console.log('Y ' + e.pageY);
});
```

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I would like to do from here is determine if the `Y` position is increasing more rapidly than the `X` position is increasing or decreasing to determine if the user is intending to move their mouse downward into the mega-menu panel or not.

Comment: So you store the last position(s) and figure it out.

Comment: That much I figured, but I'm not sure how I would determine which of those numbers was increasing more rapidly

Comment: Wouldn't you just compare the deltaX vs deltaY for the same time period? The bias of travel would be in the direction of the dimension with the larger delta.

Comment: you don't calculate every event, you calculate every 5-10 event and see the difference in x and y, then you will know the ratio, idea is, the x,y difference is too small to calculate, so you scale it up a bit, so you can calculate the difference, ex: (1, 3) ->(1, 4)->(2, 5)->(3,5)->(3,6)->(3,7), compare(1,3) with (3,7), you know y is faster than x